# Silverlight Geometry scaling issue

Tags: silverlight, geometry, zooming

How can I implement zoom to specific point in Silverlight using geometry and ScaleTransform? Can you suggest some algorithm so that I can achieve this?  My logic is wrong.  I think I have some trouble by setting the center point of scaling.

This is my geometry data in xaml file

```
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot"  Background="Orchid" MouseWheel="PathDraw_OnMouseWheel">
  <Path x:Name="PathDraw" Stroke="Brown"  StrokeThickness="1" Margin="200,200,0,0">
    <Path.Data>
      <RectangleGeometry x:Name="rect"  Rect="80 80 80 80"/>
    </Path.Data>
  </Path>
</Canvas>
```

And below is the scaling logic.

```
private static int ZoomSteps = 0;

    private static double centerX = 0;
    private static double centerY = 0;
    private double zoomCoeff = 1.1;

    private void PathDraw_OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        double delta = e.Delta;
        if (scaleX != 1)
        {
            scaleX = delta >= 0 ? scaleX * zoomCoeff : (scaleX <= 1 ? 1 : scaleX / zoomCoeff);
            scaleY = delta >= 0 ? scaleY * zoomCoeff : (scaleY <= 1 ? 1 : scaleY/zoomCoeff);
        }
        else
        {
            scaleX = scaleY = delta >= 0 ? zoomCoeff : 1;
        }

        scale = new ScaleTransform { ScaleX = scaleX, ScaleY = scaleY,
                                     CenterX = e.GetPosition(PathDraw).X,
                                     CenterY = e.GetPosition(PathDraw).Y

        };
        rect.Transform = scale;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: I have a rectangle in xaml file included in canvas.
    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot"  Background="Orchid"   MouseWheel="PathDraw_OnMouseWheel">
        <Path x:Name="PathDraw" Stroke="Brown"  StrokeThickness="1" Margin="200,200,0,0"   >
            <Path.Data>
                <RectangleGeometry x:Name="rect"  Rect="80 80 80 80"/>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>

Comment: if (scaleX != 1) {scaleX = delta >= 0 ? scaleX * zoomCoeff : (scaleX <= 1 ? 1 : scaleX / zoomCoeff);  scaleY = delta >= 0 ? scaleY * zoomCoeff : (scaleY <= 1 ? 1 : scaleY/zoomCoeff);
                }
            else
            {
                scaleX = scaleY = delta >= 0 ? zoomCoeff : 1;
            }
            scale = new ScaleTransform { ScaleX = scaleX, ScaleY = scaleY,
                                         CenterX = e.GetPosition(PathDraw).X,
                                         CenterY =e.GetPosition(PathDraw).Y
            };
            rect.Transform = scale;

Comment: but this works not correct

Comment: Include this code in your question, it\`s really hard to read it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a Margin at the Path and a Geometry that has an inherent offset (rectangle upper left corner at 80,80) you should separate scaling from translation by using two transforms:

```
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot"  Background="AliceBlue" MouseWheel="PathDraw_OnMouseWheel">
    <Path x:Name="PathDraw" Stroke="Brown" StrokeThickness="1">
        <Path.Data>
            <RectangleGeometry x:Name="rect" Rect="0 0 80 80">
                <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform"/>
                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransform"
                                            X="100" Y="100"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
            </RectangleGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

With this your MouseWheel event handler becomes as simple as this:

```
private double zoomCoeff = 1.1;

private void PathDraw_OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var deltaScale = (e.Delta > 0) ? zoomCoeff : (1d / zoomCoeff);
    var position = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);
    var dx = position.X - translateTransform.X;
    var dy = position.Y - translateTransform.Y;

    translateTransform.X = position.X - deltaScale * dx;
    translateTransform.Y = position.Y - deltaScale * dy;
    scaleTransform.ScaleX *= deltaScale;
    scaleTransform.ScaleY *= deltaScale;
}
```

You may now also independently manipulate the translation in a MouseMove handler in order to drag the rectangle.